# Laptop camera pinout

Tags: laptop, camera, pin

I have an asus 04081-00094700 camera with red, (twisted) green blue, (twisted) Gray white, purple. I have found continuity with the purple and ground as well as the red but its with resistance. I assumed that purple was ground and red positive with either blue green or white gray being the data lines but I cant get it to connect. I am using a coin cell battery at 3v which just may not be enough as it needs 3.3v and god knows if it has the amps. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most camera's are usb devices, so I think it may be a standard usb pinout.

Comment: Yeah imma just trying to find what the colours are. I just made a voltage devider but its getting hot so I think I miss identified on as vcc when its ground. Looking for any data sheets

Comment: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-connector-pinout

Comment: I know the USB ones but the laptop colours are non standard. I made some guesses using open board and the pin out but I just dont think I am giving it power correctly nor getting the data lines right